# Lighttpd rewrite with dot (.) in URL

Tags: rewrite, lighttpd, url

I've an installation of lighttpd under Debian running a small API. The current rewrite rules are:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)
```

The ideia is to (like usual on Apache):

1. If any static file is called just serve the static file right away;
2. If a URL is not found as a static file rewrite the request to `index.php`;

It works fine most of the times, however there's a problem, if the URL contains a DOT `.` it will just treat it as a static file causing a 404 error (because of the first line).

How can I make sure this doesn't happen and the request is rewritten to `index.php`? Also there are some conditions:

- I can't really predict the location of the static files, it should check if the file really exists not just "oh it has a dot, must be static" or "if folder X don't rewrite";
- The URLs might contain more than one dot, potentially a max of 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can be done using Lighty's [server.error-handler-404 option](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Server_error-handler-404Details) with given index.php as error page.
If you are proccessing some additional information about wrong URL (I see /$1 in second rewrite rule) you may try to get this via PHP's SERVER_HTTP_REFERER.

Answer (score -1):

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$0/$1"
)
```

- REBOOT :

Comment: Could you use [edit] to expand on why the addition of `$0/` in the last line makes this a good suggestion?  I suspect you're right, but some explanation would certainly help future readers.